# Opencv 2.4.6 FeatureDetector seg fault

Tags: c++, opencv, segmentation-fault

```
cv::Ptr<cv::FeatureDetector> detector = cv::FeatureDetector::create("SIFT");
cv::Ptr<cv::DescriptorExtractor> descriptor = cv::DescriptorExtractor::create("SIFT"); 
std::vector<cv::KeyPoint> keypoints;
detector->detect(src_image, keypoints);
```

Getting a segmentation fault at line 4 with opencv2.4.6. The code works if I use any of the previous opencv versions.

Please help.

Comment: is your image (`src_image`) loading properly?

Comment: Call `cv::initModule_nonfree()` at the beginning.

Comment: I am sure that src_image has no issues.

Comment: cv::initModule_nonfree(); - I am getting "No member named initModule_nonfree() in the namespace error. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks jet47 - my project was missing to link opencv_nonfree library.